# Can run this query via SQL in <1 seconds, but aggregate MongoDB can't run in under 45 minutes from the same dataset with same indexes

Tags: mongodb, performance, indexing, aggregate-functions

I have a dataset (11m rows) that consists of payments made to companies, structured like this:

```
id : 12345678,
company_id : 123456,
payment_value : 50,
payer_id: 111111,
payment_date: "20/01/2017"
payer_name: "John Smith",
...<70ish more columns with mostly blank data>...
```

There are 600k company_ids and I want to group these and show the company_id with the highest total payment value

This is the Mongo Shell (DB version: 4.0.1) code I have:

```
db.pay.aggregate([
 {$project: {_id:1, company_id:1, payment_value:1}},
 {$group: {_id: "$company_id", total_value: {$sum: "$payment_value"}}},
 {$sort: {total_value: -1},
 {$limit: 1}],
 {allowDiskUse: true})
```

That does not run in less than 45 minutes! I have an index on the company_id and this seems like a straight forward query

I loaded the same into a PostgresDB and wrote:

```
SELECT 
company_id,
SUM(payment_value)
FROM payments
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 2 DESC
LIMIT 1
```

And that took <1 second. I'm using the same index methodology for the MongoDB collection and Postgres table

What am I doing wrong here with MongoDB?

Thanks for your time

Comment: At a glance, this _does_ look strange.

Comment: Could it be the 600k unique companies that i'm grouping on? Is there anything that you'd change? There are 41k records with blank values for the company_id, but when doing {$match: {company_id: {$ne: ""}}} performance is no different

Comment: This query will require a full collection scan, so indexing doesn't figure into it.

Comment: @MassiveOwl Nah, looks fine to (sleepy) me. If I had that dataset, I'd try it on my machine, but you probably can't share yours, and I don't feel like generating a synthetic one. :)

Comment: That's fair enough - are there any best practices you'd consider that I may not be doing? I am doing $project at the start to cut down the number of fields that are passed to the $group - Could it be that I should create a collection from the $project and then run my query off of that? I realise i'm being misleading, i'll update my question as there are about 70 columns (but most have blanks)

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: You could start by removing the initial `$project` stage, as that's just adding overhead.

Comment: Is that not reducing the amount of data passed to be grouped though?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, I messaged you on Codementor

Comment: @MassiveOwl No, the `$group` will only read the fields involved in the grouping regardless.

Comment: @MassiveOwl in general terms, MongoDB works very differently from SQL databases, so what's best for SQL wouldn't be best for MongoDB, and vice versa. MongoDB is not a drop-in replacement for SQL databases, so SQL-style optimization wouldn't work like you think it does. You also have a $sort after a $group, where both stages cannot use any index.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have a feeling it could be the ulimits and rlimits - just reading about this. Going to set them as high as possible and report back on performacne

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to improve performance somewhat:

- Change the limits for the available resources for MongoDB by setting the ulimits and rlimits in the terminal
  -Use allowDishUse: true at the end of aggregate queries